# Question about zero set of Brownian motion

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, brownian-motion

I was reading the posted to solutions to one of the questions on a probability midterm and couldn't figure out how to justify one of the steps.

Let $\{B_t\}_{t\geq 0}$ be a Brownian motion and $Z(\omega) = \{t\geq 0 : B_t(\omega) = 0\}$ its zero set. The question is to compute
$$
\mathbb P[Z \cap [1,2] = \emptyset].
$$
The very first step is to notice that the conditional probability
$$
\mathbb P[Z \cap [1,2] \mid B_1 = x] = \mathbb P[\sup_{t \leq 1} B_t < |x|],
$$ 
but I'm not seeing this equality. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Is it just $Z\cap [1,2]$ in the conditional probability?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand

Comment: @Julius: It should say "$Z \cap [1,2]=\emptyset$" in the conditional probability. It's true because $(B_t-B_1)_{t\in[1,2]}$ has the same distribution as $(B_t)_{t \in [0,1]}$, and because the event $\{ Z \cap [1,2]=\emptyset\}$ is the same as the event $\{\sup_{t\in[1,2]}B_t-B_1<|B_1|\}$, i.e, it's the same as the event $\{\sup_{t \in [1,2]}B_t-B_1<|x|\}$ given that $B_1=x$.

Comment: So $\mathbb P[Z\cap [1,2]] = \mathbb P[\sup_{1\leq t\leq 2}|B_t - B_1| < |B_1|] = \mathbb P[\sup_{t\leq 1} B_t< |B_1|]$?

Comment: Almost: $$P\bigg(Z \cap [1,2]= \emptyset \big| B_1=x\bigg) = P\bigg(\sup_{t\in [1,2]}B_t-B_1<|B_1| \big| B_1=x\bigg)\\ = P\bigg(\sup_{t\in [1,2]}B_t-B_1<|x|\bigg) = P\bigg(\sup_{t \in [0,1]} B_t < |x|\bigg)$$